# Не получается привязать адрес к сокету

Tags: php, сокет

Доброго времени суток!

Пытаюсь разобраться, как работают сокеты. Нижеприведенный код, "Простой сервер TCP/IP", взял из официального мануала по PHP, а именно [отсюда](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/sockets.examples.php) ...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Позволяет скрипту ожидать соединения бесконечно. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Включает скрытое очищение вывода так, что мы видим данные
 * как только они появляются. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 10000;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "Не удалось выполнить socket_create(): причина: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "Не удалось выполнить socket_bind(): причина: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "Не удалось выполнить socket_listen(): причина: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "Не удалось выполнить socket_accept(): причина: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    /* Отправляем инструкции. */
    $msg = "\nДобро пожаловать на тестовый сервер PHP. \n" .
        "Чтобы отключиться, наберите 'выход'. Чтобы выключить сервер, наберите 'выключение'.\n";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "Не удалось выполнить socket_read(): причина: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
            break 2;
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($buf == 'выход') {
            break;
        }
        if ($buf == 'выключение') {
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        $talkback = "PHP: Вы сказали '$buf'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        echo "$buf\n";
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

...но он выдает следущую ошибку:

> Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [10048]: Normalerweise darf jede Socketadresse (Protokoll, Netzwerkadresse oder Anschluss) nur jeweils einmal verwendet werden.

В переводе с немецкого это звучит так: "Обычно каждый адрес сокета (протокол, сетевой адрес или порт) разрешается использовать только один раз."

Не понимаю, где именно я использовал сокет несколько раз, ведь сам скрипт я запускал всего одинажды, т.е. сокет инициализировался всего один раз соответственно. Целый день пытаюсь разобраться...пока безрезультатно.

**UPD:** Сервер Open Server Panel 5.4.3. Apache 2.4 + PHP 8.1